# How to post values from RestAssured to JSon and get a value from it?

Tags: json, rest, rest-assured

```
{"service_request":  {"service_type":"Registration","partner":"1010101","validity":1,"validity_unit":"Year","quantity":1,"center":"1020301","template":"2020301"}}
```

I have JSON values as above obtained from Request Payload, when I post data from the web page. I want to post this data from RESTAssured in java and want to get the returned value? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to check https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#specifying-request-data

I imagine you are trying to do a POST using Rest-Assured.For that simplest and easy way is.. Save your payload as String. If you have payload as JSONObject, use toJSONString() to convert it to String

```
String payload = "yourpayload";
String responseBody = given().contentType(ContentType.JSON).body(payload).
when().post(url).then().assertThat().statusCode(200).and()
extract().response().asString();
```

Above code, post your payload to given Url, verify response code and convert response body to a String. You can do assertion without converting to String as well like

```
given().contentType(ContentType.JSON).body(payload).
when().post(url).then().assertThat().statusCode(200).
and().assertThat().body("service_request.partner", equalTo("1010101"));
```

Comment: Firstly, I know nothing about JSON... I just get request payload from the firefox -> inspect element -> Network -> params tab. I tried as you said like this.
    String responseBody =    RestAssured.given().contentType(ContentType.JSON).body(payload).when().post(PortalURLS.PORTAL_SERVICE_TOKEN_URL).then().assertThat().statusCode(200).and().extract().response().toString();

But, It's not working....


Assume that I have already logged in to the portal through RestAssured in a method earlier...

Comment: FAILED: PortalLogin
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
Expected status code <200> doesn't match actual status code <302>.

I am getting error like above.... Actually when I debug in the firefox, there the response code is 200... But, I don't know How 302 is coming in RestAssured.

Comment: Can you make sure that, you are using correct URL. A 302 indicates that "The requested resource resides temporarily under a different URI. Since the redirection might be altered on occasion, the client SHOULD continue to use the Request-URI for future requests. This response is only cacheable if indicated by a Cache-Control or Expires header field.".